# IPTables - Port to another ip & port (from the inside)

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, firewall

I currently have a NAS box running under port 80. To access the NAS from the outside, I mapped the port 8080 to port 80 on the NAS as follow:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.25.2:80`

This is working like a charm. However, this is working only if I am accessing the website from the outside of the network (at work, at diffrent house, etc). So when I type in `mywebsite.com:8080`, IPTables do the job correctly and everything is working fine.

Now, the problem I have is, how can I redirect this port from the inside of the network ? My domain name `mywebsite.com` point to my router (my linux server) from the inside (10.32.25.1) but I want to redirect port 8080 to port 80 on 10.32.25.2 from the inside.

Any clue?

#### Edit #1

Attempting to help facilitate this question I put this diagram together. Please feel free to update if it's incorrect or misrepresenting what you're looking for.

```
                                 iptables
                                     |                   .---------------.
    .-,(  ),-.                       v               port 80             |
 .-(          )-.        port 8080________               |               |
(    internet    )------------>[_...__...°]------------->|      NAS      |
 '-(          ).-'     10.32.25.2    ^   10.32.25.1      |               |
     '-.( ).-'                       |                   |               |
                                     |                   '---------------'
                                     |
                                     |
                                   __  _ 
                                  [__]|=|
                                  /::/|_|
```

Comment: @slm Exactly. Nothing happen on 10.32.25.2:8080 because the server is on port 80. From the outside, the NAT redirect from port 8080 to port 80 on the specified IP (10.32.25.2). NET -> NAT:8080 -> 10.32.25.2:80. I need the rule from the inside and I don't know what to put there.

Comment: @slm Yes. I don't know how I can achieve something like that. I want to say `10.32.25.1:8080` redirect to `10.32.25.2:80`. My rule above is working from the outside, but not from the inside of my network. So if I am at the office, I can access my NAS from http://website.com:8080 and it's completly transparent. From my home, website.com:8080 point to 10.32.25.1 because it's my router aka Linux server. I want to redirect the port 8080 to the NAS also on port 80 but again, in a transparent way.

Comment: @slm Yes, everything is fine and working. I just want to redirect port 10.32.25.1:8080 to 10.32.25.2:80 from the internal network.

Comment: also mention interface like `eth0 10.32.25.2`, so that we can able to write iptables use based on inbound interface

Comment: Opps sorry, I just saw.. you already solve the issue..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found how-to. First, I had to add `-i eth1` to my "outside" rule (eth1 is my WAN connection). I also needed to add two others rules. Here in the end what I came with :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.32.25.2:80
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 10.32.25.2:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.32.25.2 --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: The second rule is not necessary, as the first rule already contains that...

Comment: The first rule restricts the preroute only if it's arriving on interface eth1.  The second rule is more general as it applies to all interfaces.  Beware loops!

Comment: This will work as shown IF the `FORWARD` table is set to `ACCEPT` by default.  If you have a default `DROP` `FORWARD` section, you need to add a rule to allow packets to flow; something like `iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`.

Answer (score 4):

You also forgot to mention that package forwarding should be enabled to be able to perform destination NAT. By default, it's usually off, so iptables rules will not work. It can be enabled by issuing:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I would have been pulling my hair out for hours!

Answer (score 3):

First allow forwarding with

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Then set iptable rules with

```
IF=eth1
PORT_FROM=8080
PORT_TO=80
DEST=10.32.25.2
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i $IF -p tcp --dport $PORT_FROM -j DNAT --to $DEST:$PORT_TO
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d $DEST --dport $PORT_TO -j MASQUERADE
```

You can put these lines into `/etc/rc.local` for example. Note: since Debian jessie make it executable and enabled the rc.local service via

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to verify that you have the forwarding activated:

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

If not `1`, run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

If you want traffic hitting 10.32.25.1 on port 80 and 443 to be forwarded to 10.32.25.2's 80port then you should use the below rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.32.25.1 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.32.25.2:80
```