# HTTPS Redirecting to Subdomain

Tags: apache-httpd, certificates

I have a subdomain at `https://mail.example.com` with a valid certificate. However, if someone were to accidentally type in `https://example.com` to the address bar, the certificate for the mail server is picked up instead, and thus displays the subdomain contents.

How can I fix this using apache's vhost config files?

Comment: Can you explain the server setup a bit more. Is this all on one server or multiple? Also is there an Apache server listening on port 80 of the server that is responding to example.com? You could also save on the overhead and just make the port 80 of example.com do a port redirect to the server mail.example.com via iptables.

Comment: Something like this but this is just a thought: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76300/iptables-port-to-another-ip-port-from-the-inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://mail.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

only when your certificate is valid for each domain. The odd thing about it when using https, you'll need also to include your certs for the Vhost.

Comment: I tried doing this...do I need to launch separate vhosts for ssl and non-ssl verisons of my site, or can I add multiple vhost statements to 1 file for a particular site? Also, apache warns me about `vhost overlap` when I have mutiple files running on port 443. How do I resolve this?

Comment: It's up to you, it depends what you want. A vhost syntax is `<VirtualHost ...></VirtualHost>`. You can put as many as you want in one file. They must be unique. It seems you'll need to check your configs. Simple dumb testing, remove all, insert one, restart, check for errors, insert one more, and so on.

Comment: This solved my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658017/apache-error-default-virtualhost-overlap-on-port-443

Since your answer was closest I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

#### Method #1 - use iptables

This will port forward all the traffic to ports 80 & 443 from the server responding to `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` to some other server using just `iptables`.

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0  -p tcp --dport 80 \
     -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to www.example.com:80

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0  -p tcp --dport 443 \
     -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j DNAT --to www.example.com:443

$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m conntrack \
     --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

$ sudo iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -j MASQUERADE
```

#### Method #2 - using Apache

In Apache you're going to want to do a URL rewrite rule that will intercept these requests and append the `www.` to them. Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmple\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

The `R=permanent,L` makes the above rule get invoked just 1 time, and then clients will know from that point forward to go to www.example.com. This is a [HTTP 301 response status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). Clients will only know about the URLs moving until they're restarted, so this will need to remain inplace indefinitely.

#### Method #3 - via the registrar

I don't recall this method off the top of my head, but I seem to remember that when you setup a domainname that there are often times options to map the toplevel domain to a particular host. Perhaps your registrar provides similar features.

This would be the most desirable method, if plausible, since it will keep your environment simpler, and cut down on the extra hops you'll have to now incur each time a client accesses your site.

Comment: I fear the iptables solution will not work because in the SSL handshake the validity of a certificate is checked by the client. I.e. if the certificate is valid for www.example.com then the client will reject it when connect to mail.example.com. Perhaps it will work with a wildcard certificate, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: @bersch - exactly, I've used this for *.example.com type certs (wildcard certs).

Comment: To reiterate, what I'm trying to do:

A client mistakenly requests https://example.com/. There is no certificate set up for example.com, however, there is one on mail.example.com. My issue is, the browser grabs the certificate and displays the contents of mail.example.com, even though the url in the address bar stays as an "self-signed" example.com.

Comment: @NoelForte - the ip tables method should work b/c the redirect is occurring at the TCP level, not the application level (HTTP).

Comment: @NoelForte - you're going to have to try these to see which suites your needs. There are too many variables for us to tell you exactly which will work and which won't, I'm afraid. But every method I've mentioned I've used at one time or another.

Comment: @NoelForte - if this helps, think of it this way. When the browser initiates the connection to example.com, the iptables rule will redirect to mail.example.com before the browser has even had a chance to request any certs from example.com.

Comment: @slm the client also checks the reverse host name in order to prevent man in the middle attacks. So I assume both hosts have the same reverse DNS name. Some Oracle soft can configure it: [Using Host Name Verification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13707/ssl.htm#i1194395)

Comment: @bersch - yes I'm familiar with this. Hence why I showed 3 methods 8-). You'll have to pick the one that works for you.

Comment: The apache way doesn't work. Why is a one URL using the certificate of another? The certificate isn't even associated with the main domain...

Comment: @NoelForte - I really want to assist you but I need more information. It's like trying to debug a problem blindfolded. Can you get any output from the Apache logs (example.com's Apache) when a browser attempt to connect?

Comment: @NoelForte - see this SF Q&A. Sounds like your situation too. http://serverfault.com/questions/83658/apache-ssl-new-domain-redirect

Comment: @NoelForte - another thread to look at from SF: http://serverfault.com/questions/447222/ssl-certificates-for-domain-without-www/447224#447224

Comment: Right. I'll try to explain more thoroughly. All of these URL's are on virtual hosts. I have purchased a certificate for `http://mail.example.com` to use on my mail server. The issue I'm encountering is if I navigate to `https://example.com/`, the main root domain name, I'm shown a warning that the server responded from mail.example.com, not example.com, and the URL for the certificate doesn't match. Upon proceeding, the URL in the address bar stays the same, but the contents shown are those at mail.example.com. Why is the client picking up an invalid cert and then being taken elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you will need to have an SSL certificate.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName domain.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.domain.com/
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain/domain.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain/domain.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```